# How to shift a quadratic line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, geometry

How to shift a quadratic blue line to lower position? Now the space between the curves is not the same because of a quadratic function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [8, 8]

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y = x**2
ax.set_ylim(-0.3, 1.06)
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.scatter(1/2*(ax.get_xlim()[0] + ax.get_xlim()[1]), 0.15, marker = 'o', s=900, facecolors='none')
width_l = ax.get_ylim()[1] - ax.get_ylim()[0]
ax.plot(x, y - 0.1*width_l)

plt.show()
```

[image]

The desired result is two parallel lines:
[image]

Comment: The blue line is the original line,  what are you trying to get?

Comment: @DavidS It seems the post would like to create a parallel curve instead of a shifted curve. A parallel curve would have a fixed perpendicular distance. A shifted curve has a fixed distance measured in the `y` direction. Such a parallel curve is a hard mathematical issue. See e.g. the [wikipedia discussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve)

Comment: Yes, the blue line is the original and I would like to get a parallel line.

Comment: Using the parametric form of a parabola `(2at, at^2)`, apply [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve#Parallel_curve_of_a_parametrically_given_curve)

Comment: But I have also curves with more complicated shapes in GridSpec. What about an overplot?

Comment: Sorry, what is an `overplot`?

Comment: Something like one plot over another and it should be transparent to see both lines. I do not know whether it exists in python.

Comment: Shapely has [`buffer`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.buffer) method which does something similar.

Comment: I tried to run an example buffer.py and I get an error: ImportError:  cannot import name 'SIZE'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that calculates the normals from the curve, and plots parallel lines at a given distance specified as the `length` of the normal:

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

def get_parallels(length=.1):
    
    px, py = [], []
    
    for idx in range(len(x)-1):
        x0, y0, xa, ya = x[idx], y[idx], x[idx+1], y[idx+1]
        dx, dy = xa-x0, ya-y0
        norm = math.hypot(dx, dy) * 1/length
        dx /= norm
        dy /= norm        
        px.append(x0-dy)
        py.append(y0+dx)
    return px, py


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [8, 8]

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y = x**2
ax.set_ylim(-0.3, 1.06)
ax.plot(x, y)
for length in (-.3, -.2, -.1, .1, .2, .3, .4):
    ax.plot(*get_parallels(length=length))


plt.show()
```

or plotting an unreasonable number:

```
for length in (ndx*.025 for ndx in range(-100, 20) if ndx != 0 ):
    ax.plot(*get_parallels(length=length))
```

[image]

Comment: Could I ask you a question in Edit after advice I added to my question, please?

Comment: Glad i could help @Elena. You should probably ask a new question (it is free ;-)) : (1) I already answered the original question, and the additions are really another domain; (2) I don't readily know how to do what you are now asking, and (3) your new question can build up on my answer, and attract input from others that are better able to solve your new problem. For clarity, I rolled back your edits.

Comment: Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65317561/how-to-plot-parallel-curves